# Unable to use sidebar with st.column

Tags: python, streamlit

I am building a stream lit app, I defined st.column and sidebar in my code. when I first click on button 1, then I check on sidebar, my click on button 1 would disappear, is there a way that I can keep them both?

```py
col1, col2, col3 = st.columns([.4,.5,1])

m = st.markdown("""
<style>
div.stButton > button:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(0,250,154);
}
</style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)


with col1:
    button1 = st.button('aa')

with col2:
    button2 = st.button('bb')

with col3:
    button3 = st.button('cc')

option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x1', value=True)
option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x2')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work properly with `st.button`. Instead of using `st.button`, you could use `st.multiselect`, like this:

```py
import streamlit as st

col1, col2, col3 = st.columns([.4,.5,1])

opts = st.multiselect("Options", ["aa", "bb", "cc"])

option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x1', value=True)
option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('x2')

st.write(f"aa: {'aa' in opts}, bb: {'bb' in opts}, cc: {'cc' in opts}")
st.write(f"option_1: {option_1}, option_2: {option_2}")
```

Then, the state of the checkboxes and the multiselect options does not reset after every click.

[image: Final view after using the code above; some input are True, some are False]

---

If you don't want more than one "aa", "bb" and "cc" set to `True`, you can use a `st.selectbox` instead of the `st.multiselect`.